# Why can not get application controller through needs?

Tags: ember.js

I implemented a flash(message) view inside application template, it use application's msg attribute to show site wide message:

```
<div class='application-main container'>
  {{#if msg}}
    {{view Yu.FlashView}}
  {{/if}}

  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

Part of my router:

```
Yu.Router.map ->
  @resource 'user', { path: '/users/:user_id' }
```

And user route:

```
Yu.UserRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    Yu.User.find(params.user_id)

  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    @_super controller, model

    @controllerFor('avatar').set 'model', model.get('avatar')
    @controllerFor('basicinfo').set 'model', model.get('basicinfo')

  renderTemplate: (controller, model) ->
    @_super controller, model

    @render 'avatar', into: 'user', outlet: 'avatar'
    @render 'basicinfo', into: 'user', outlet: 'basicinfo'
```

As you can see when enter user route I setup basicinfo controller and put it into outlet.
Here is the question: I "needs" application controller in basicinfo controller but I seems not work:

```
Yu.BasicinfoController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  needs: 'application'.w()

  update: ->
    @content.save()
    @content.on('becameInvalid', ->
      window.console.log(Em.inspect(@get('controllers.application')))  !-> prints "undefined"
      @get('controllers.application').set 'msg', 'please refresh'      !-> msg did not show
    )
    @set 'inEditModel', false
```

And I am very confused with needs api, What is wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you use a double arrow `=>` for the becameInvalid callback? So that `this` is the controller?

Comment: Sorry, My fault. It solve the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the problem is in your code, but here's a simple example demonstrating it working:  http://jsfiddle.net/scottned/NQKvy/32/

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
    {{#each customer in customers}}
      <li>{{customer.firstName}} {{customer.lastName}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>

App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.ApplicationController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    people: [
      {firstName: 'Kris', lastName: 'Selden'},
      {firstName: 'Luke', lastName: 'Melia'},
      {firstName: 'Formerly Alex', lastName: 'Matchneer'}
    ]
});

App.IndexController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    content: Em.Object.create({}),
    needs: 'application',
    customersBinding: 'controllers.application.people'
});
```